# AOT Compiler to Shrink Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, containers, aot

Is using an AOT compiler such as GCj or Excelsior Jet appropriate if we're aiming to shrink the size of a Docker container?

The largest part of the container is the JRE, and we're looking for ways to trim this down. Our microservices are kb in size, it seems odd that we're having to deploy 110MB containers.

Comment: Slightly off topic so I'm not adding this as an answer. Suggestion: Use a Java official image such as java:openjdk-8-jdk-alpine which is built on alpine linux and therefore much smaller.

Comment: We tried this, but the image is still over 90mb.

Answer (score 0):

From version 11.3 onwards, Excelsior JET supports [Compact Profiles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/compactprofiles/compactprofiles.html), which may help.